# Copying magicCookie from audiofile to audioqueue fails

Tags: swift, core-audio

I am probably the 1000th person trying to learn CoreAudio with the help of the famous book "Learning Core Audio" by Adamson/Avila. And probably the 1000th person struggling to convert the original code examples into modern Swift.

I got the example from chapter 5 in the book (Playing a file using AudioQueueService) working, but whenever I try to play a file in a format which uses a magicCookie the code crashes.

I reduced the code to only what is necessary to reproduce the error:

```
import AudioToolbox

// user data struct needed for the callback

struct MyPlayer {
    var playbackFile: AudioFileID?
}

// callback stub

func myAQOutputCallback(inUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, inQueue: AudioQueueRef, inCompleteAQBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef) {

}

func copyEncoderCookieToQueue(_ file: AudioFileID, _ queue: AudioQueueRef) {

    var propertySize: UInt32 = 0
    let result: OSStatus = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(file, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &propertySize, nil)

    if result == noErr && propertySize > 0 {

        var magicCookie = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount:Int(propertySize), alignment: Int(propertySize))

        var error = AudioFileGetProperty(file, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &propertySize, &magicCookie)

        // up to this point everything works as expected

        error = AudioQueueSetProperty(queue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, magicCookie, propertySize)
        magicCookie.deallocate()
    }
}

func main() {

    let kPlaybacklFileLocation = "/Users/\(NSUserName())/Desktop/70s Ballad Drums 01.caf"
    var player = MyPlayer()

    let myFileURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, kPlaybacklFileLocation as CFString, .cfurlposixPathStyle, false)
    var error = AudioFileOpenURL(myFileURL!, .readPermission, 0, &player.playbackFile)

    var dataFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
    var propSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: dataFormat))
    error = AudioFileGetProperty(player.playbackFile!, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &propSize, &dataFormat)

    var queue: AudioQueueRef?
    error = AudioQueueNewOutput(&dataFormat, myAQOutputCallback, &player, nil, nil, 0, &queue)

    copyEncoderCookieToQueue(player.playbackFile!, queue!)
}

main()
```

To test it you can put one of Apples AppleLoop files that come with GarageBand onto the desktop. The MagicCookie seems to extract properly, but trying to write it to the AudioQueue results in error EXC_BAD_ACCESS, which I learned means something is trying to access a released object, but as far as I can see all parameters should still be valid.

I have no idea how to further investigate what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try not deallocating the magic cookie storage until many (200?) milliseconds after the Audio Queue is shut down for good.  The queue can call into an async thread that uses the cookie who know when.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing magicCookie.deallocate() does not work. It does give the same error. I don't think this could be causing the problem, as it is only an intermediate var to store the cookieData taken from the file before it gets passed to the queue. It is my understanding that the queue copies the cookie data into its own memory. In the original code from the book the pointer is free'd.